# Flexbox grow and shrink property columns vs determined width columns for responsive grid system

Tags: css, responsive-design, flexbox, grid-system

Lately I've been learning flexbox and how to make my own grid system. When making grid system using floats, we determine number of columns per layout and each column's width in percentages. But when using flexbox, all the layout tutorials I saw are simply using `flex-direction: row;` and `flex: 1` 
for columns, to make all of them equal size, equal gutter, centered and in one row. But when I checked flexboxgrid source code on github, they are using same principle as bootstrap 3. They have columns for different screen sizes, 12 columns and `flex-grow`, `shrink` are disabled. Instead, each column is determined in width percentages, like `col-xs-1` `max-width: 8.33%`.

Now I'm wondering what's the difference between these two techniques and which one is more preferable. I mean determining width for each column requires a lot of counting, while using flex grow property just fulfills the whole viewport in main axis with equally sized columns and gutters.

Comment: There's a problem with your question: *all the layout tutorials I saw are simply using ... `flex: 1` with `justify-content: space between`* If you use `flex: 1`, flex items consume all available space. As a result, the `justify-content` property has no effect (there's no remaining space to apply `space-between`).

Comment: Aside from that, your question is generally too broad for Stack Overflow. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What should I do then? Question is specific, why would someone use one technique over another. I edites original post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr**

They are not techniques to achieve the same result, they do different things.

---

[**Flexbox grid**](http://flexboxgrid.com/) uses `flex-basis` to determine `width` in flex container's main axis. It does not use `flex: 1;` on flex items because that is equivalent to `flex: 1 1 0;`. Which means `flex-basis` would have a value of `0`, and the flex items sizes would be proportional to the specified grow and shrink factor, both having a value of `1`.

---

**Example**

`col-xs-1` with a flex-basis of `0` specified from `flex: 1;` would grow as if it was `col-xs-12` if it is the only child, if there is another `col-xs-1` like this as a sibling, then it would grow as if it was `col-xs-6` and so forth.

It is expected for every `col-xs-1` to fill `1/12`, *(8.33333333%)*, of the container, which would not be the case using `flex: 1;`.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
article {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
[class^="col-"],
[class*="col-"] {
  flex: 0 0 auto; /* flex-grow: 0; flex-shrink: 0; flex-basis: auto; */
}
.row {
  display: flex;
  margin-right: -.5rem;
  margin-left: -.5rem;
}
.col-xs-1 {
  padding-right: .5rem;
  padding-left: .5rem;
  flex-basis: 8.33333333%;
}
.box-row {
  min-height: 1em;
  background: #007FFF;
}
article:last-of-type .col-xs-1 {
  flex: 1;  /* Same as flex: 1 1 0; */
}
```

```html
<article class="row">
  <section class="col-xs-1">
    <div class="box-row"></div>
  </section>
  <section class="col-xs-1">
    <div class="box-row"></div>
  </section>
</article>

<article class="row">
  <section class="col-xs-1">
    <div class="box-row"></div>
  </section>
  <section class="col-xs-1">
    <div class="box-row"></div>
  </section>
</article>
```